# Multiple connection to php script on behalf of the same user

Tags: php, apache

I have long running operations in my php app. It uses mod_rewrite so all traffic is heading to index.php. When it is doing those long running tasks it doesn't response in other cards in browser until task ends.

Is there any configuration allowing to multiple connection to one php script on behalf of the same user?

Comment: You're using sessions, right?

Comment: Yes I'am. It's my index.php

`$start = microtime(true);  
  
error_reporting(E_ALL);  
  
session_start();
define('APP_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);  
  
require_once APP_PATH.'application/config.php';  
require_once APP_PATH.'application/app.php';  
  
App::app()->run();`

Comment: Use `session_write_close()` as soon as possible: "Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as soon as all changes to session variables are done."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax or WebSocket. But there is no way to solve it with a pure server side solution because of blocking (operations are executed in order). You can try multi-threading, there is a pthread extension for PHP, but you have to compile PHP with it.

Other solution is to use some sort of work queue if you don't have to wait for the tasks to end and return some response from them.

Comment: Thanks for reply, It looks promising but requires dedicated server. So far I'm thinking about queue long running operations, store them in DB and write another php file just for doing them via CRON task.

Comment: You don't need a dedicated server. Check IronMQ (http://www.iron.io). It has a limited number of jobs for free. IMO it is better than making extra load on the server (especially if it is not a dedicated server). It has a nice client written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

@mlask reply about `session_write_close()` did exactly what i wanted. After calling `session_write_close()` next connection where accepted immediately.

more about [session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)